# Edit Word table using officer package

Tags: r, officer

Using "officer" I'm trying to edit the values of a Word table.
Pretty straight forward to find the "paragraph" containing it

```
library(officer)

doc = read_docx('template.docx')
doc = cursor_begin(doc)
doc = cursor_reach(doc,"Some text")
print(doc)
```

and I get a document that looks like:

```
* Content at cursor location:
 row_id is_header cell_id                    text col_span row_span
1.1       1     FALSE       1                   D            1        1
1.5       2     FALSE       1                                1        1
1.9       3     FALSE       1             Some text          1        1
1.13      4     FALSE       1                                1        1
2.2       1     FALSE       2            More text           1        1
```

But, then what? There doesn't seem to be any way of directly altering the content of this table...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `body_replace_all_text` for that task.

```
library(officer)


doc <- read_docx()
doc <- body_add_table(doc, iris, style = "table_template")

doc = cursor_reach(doc, "setosa")
doc <- body_replace_all_text(doc, old_value = "setosa", 
  new_value = "coco", only_at_cursor = TRUE)
print(doc, target = "test.docx")
```

Comment: Sweet! Not ideal, since i was hoping to add text to empty cells, but i can add a placeholder text in there an replace that. This works, thanks!

Comment: depending on what you really want to do, there could be easier solutions. For example you can get a data.frame from these data (see here: https://davidgohel.github.io/officer/articles/officer_reader.html#word-tables) and replace then the word table with a modified version of the data.