# Modify a word document using R

Tags: r, ms-word

This [link](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/create-and-format-word-documents-using-r-software-and-reporters-package) explains how to add a simple or customized table in a word document, by using an `R` code based on `ReporteRs` package.

My task is quite different. I already have a word file: [file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qdh6kxlmgjty77m/file.docx?dl=0). I would like to add a new row for each of the tables (i.e. Red, Yellow, Blue, Black datasets). The first column should be today's date (by `Sys.Date()` I guess), the other cells could be random (they are not important at this level).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, "ReporteRs has been rewritten. The new package is officer. [...] Native Microsoft charts can be produced with package `mschart`. Please use `officer` instead of ReporteRs" (D. Gohel *in* [ReporteRs](https://github.com/davidgohel/ReporteRs)).

I never need to edit a table in a word file but, with `officer`, you should read the data → import tables as dataframes and made some modifications in R language → export a new .docx which fit your need (with the old paragraph and the 'new' tables you just compute).

Alternatively, its possible to edit tables in a .docx file, which are some word-kind of 'paragraph': it's necessary to use some pointer or regex, in order to indicate which tables are edited (e.g., [package vignette](https://davidgohel.github.io/officer/articles/offcran/word.html), [SO question & answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50927835/officer-edit-word-table)).

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with the R package RDCOMClient :

```
library(DescTools)
library(RDCOMClient)

report <- GetNewWrd(template = normalizePath("C:\\...\\file.docx"))
report[["Visible"]] <- TRUE

nb_Tables <- report[["ActiveDocument"]]$Tables()$Count()

for(l in 1 : nb_Tables)
{
  obj_Table <- report[["ActiveDocument"]]$Tables(l)
  nb_Row <- obj_Table$Rows()$Count()
  nb_Col <- obj_Table$Columns()$Count()
  obj_Table$Rows()$Add()

  for(j in 1 : nb_Col)
  {
    obj_Table$Cell(nb_Row + 1, j)$Range()$InsertAfter(paste0("l : ", l, " and j : ", j))
  }
}

report[["ActiveDocument"]]$SaveAs("C:\\...\\modified_file.docx")
```